# ASP.NET MVC 5 in AWS and MongoDb, 503 Service is unavaliable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mlab

I have a web app in ASP.NET MVC 5 hosted in AWS (Elastic Beanstalk). It has a Load Balancer with 2 web servers (t2.medium). In the other hand, I have a Mongodb hosted in Mongolab (Database As A Service) with a Dedicated Cluster Plans, M1, with 1.7 GB RAM in AWS too.

I have a simple Web Api (called throught JavaScript) that is inserting in MongoDb click events of the user (log info about the behaviour of the user in the web app).

Last week, I had about 1200 users connected at the same time, and after about 10 minutes, the server began to response, 503. Service is unavaliable.

If a see the telemetry monitor about the web server in AWS, everything is fine. CPU normal (about 20%), and the servers are up.

I have read a lot about this error (App Pool of the IIS is restarting because too many errors in short time), but in my Elmah Log, I don't find exceptions.

I don't know where could be the origin of the problem, and I will show you the telemetry of the MongoDB.

Can anyone help me please?

Regards.

**EDIT:** I have installed in the EC2 instances Windows Server 2012 Core Edition with IIS 8 (no user interface)

[image]

Comment: The 503 is returned because the server has reached its max connections. Any idea what your request limit is? You may need to upgrade this or switch to an autoscaling solution. Was there an unusual load on the server? If so you may have been hit by a DDOS attack in which case you should look into ways AWS can lowers the risk or further attacks.

Comment: Where can I see the limit of request? My solution is autoscaling (for CPU performance, but I can change). Thanks.